# Insects are attracted to light, what if the light is too bright?

Tags: entomology, eyes, light

Insects are known to approach light sources. I know that they use it as navigation tools, by maintaining a constant angle between their path and the light beam. However, if a light source is exceedingly bright, I mean like "blinding" bright, would an insect still use that as navigation tool?

What I have been thinking is, the insect wouldn't use it, and try to escape from the light source. I believe this because the extreme blindness may cause the insect to damage it's eyes, although I am neither knowledgeable nor capable of confirming this.

Such a thing usually doesn't happen in nature, so I'm unsure if such a test has been made before. Nontheless any help would be great. I also understand that my definition of "bright" isn't well defined, since I don't know the maximum intensity an insect can handle. I also haven't mentioned the insect, so for consistency sake, assume it to be a **Black Witch moth** (*Ascalapha odorata*)

### tl;dr

Would an insect use a light source that's exceedingly bright to navigate?

Comment: Here's a study that addresses methods for pest control using various light parameters. Though it doesn't explicitely state it, the study does say that intensity is used for both attracting *and* repelling insects that are photoreceptive. https://rd.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/s13355-013-0219-x.pdf

Comment: "*Insects exhibit the following phototactic
behaviors: (A) **attraction** (i.e., positive phototaxis, moving
toward a light source); this response can be used
to trap pests, but the effective wavelengths and **intensities**
vary among species and (B) **repulsion** (i.e., negative phototaxis,
moving away from light); this can be used
to prevent pests from entering a cultivation area by presenting
light at wavelengths and **intensities** that repel them.*"

Comment: First, your assumption that insects use light as navigation might be wrong, the flight-to-light behaviour is still far from understood. [Link](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://amp.livescience.com/33156-moths-drawn-artificial-lights.html&ved=0ahUKEwj-1JHvuM3VAhXBKFAKHQb6D1QQFggqMAQ&usg=AFQjCNEvZ6VdsFZpHu1RIStSvd6ThfkKtg&ampcf=1). Secondly, I doubt a light can be too bright. The incandescent lights that are often used for trapping them are so bright that human are blinded by them.